# Create command similar to WRKLIBPDM

Tags: command, ibm-midrange

I wanted to create a field that is similar to how the LIB field in WRKLIBPDM command.
If I just press F4 on the WRKLIBPDM command, it will show the below. The `name` and `*generic*` are included

```
 Library  . . . . . . . . . . . .   *PRV          *PRV, name, *generic*...
```

But when I press F4 on the field itself, it will show the list but it won't show the `name` and `*generic*`.

```
*PRV    
*LIBL   
*USRLIBL
*ALL    
*ALLUSR 
*CURLIB
```

I tried to do this but it doesn't work. Though even if this work, the `name` and `*generic*` is like a hardcoded value and not any name or a generic name.

```
PARM       KWD(LIB2) TYPE(*NAME) LEN(10) RSTD(*YES) +
             DFT(*PRV) VALUES(*PRV name *generic*) +  
             PROMPT('Library')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands can handle generic names with the `*GENERIC` type

```
   PARM       KWD(LIB2) TYPE(*GENERIC) LEN(10) DFT(*PRV) SPCVAL((*PRV) +
         (*LIBL) (*USRLIBL) (*ALL) (*ALLUSR) (*CURLIB)) PROMPT('Library')
```

Choice text will be generated like this :

```
Library  . . . . . . . . . . . .   *PRV          Name, generic*, *PRV...
```

But you can override generation by setting the text in `CHOICE`

```
   PARM       KWD(LIB2) TYPE(*GENERIC) LEN(10) DFT(*PRV) SPCVAL((*PRV) +
         (*LIBL) (*USRLIBL) (*ALL) (*ALLUSR) (*CURLIB)) CHOICE('*PRV name +
         *generic*') PROMPT('Library')
```

```
Library  . . . . . . . . . . . .   *PRV          *PRV name *generic*
```

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to learn how would it look like to re-create the field so thank you for showing your solution. But it looks almost the same since I noticed that the Type is CHARACTER for the WRKLIBPDM but yours is a GENERIC NAME.